# How to use time ago javascript after minutes change to hour then day like facebook?

Tags: javascript

```js
(function timeAgo(selector) {

  console.clear();

  var dt1 = new Date("2019-12-17 13:12:34");
  var dt2 = new Date();

  var diff = (dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime());
  var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  diff -= hours * (1000 * 60 * 60);
  var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
  diff -= mins * (1000 * 60);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mins + 'minutes ago';

  setTimeout(timeAgo, 60000);

})();
```

```html
<span id="demo" />
```

Comment: You have `hours` already. Why you don't use it? What did you try and what is your problem?

Comment: checkout moment.js https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: @EganWolf the problem is when minutes don't change to hour for example current time = 15:26 and start time = 13:12 the answer should be 2 hours ago, but then after pass 1 hour it turns back 0 minute.

Comment: @AyroseRosli This is the thing that needs to be implemented. I'm asking what stops you from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use moment.js.

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()
// 8 years ago
```

Answer (score 0):

moment.js is great, you can use that but in case you are looking for a pure JS solution:

```js
(function getTimeDiff() {
  let datetime = new Date("2016-04-18 01:07:23.132446").getTime();
  let now = new Date().getTime();

  let milisecDiff = (datetime < now) ? now - datetime : datetime - now;
  let days = Math.floor(milisecDiff / 1000 / 60 / (60 * 24));
  let dateDiff = new Date(milisecDiff);

  console.log(`${days} Days ${dateDiff.getHours()} Hours ${dateDiff.getMinutes()} Minutes ${dateDiff.getSeconds()} Seconds`);
})();
```

You can further format the output to serve your use cases.